# Initialize object without pushing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have class with constructor for logging and for access to config:

```
public class SendEmaiServiceProvider
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    private readonly ILogger<SendEmaiServiceProvider> _logger;
    private readonly string _fromEmailAddress;


    public SendEmaiServiceProvider(IConfiguration config, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<SendEmaiServiceProvider> logger)
    {
        _config = config;
        _env = env;
        _logger = logger;
        _fromEmailAddress = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Email:FromEmailAddress");
    }

    public void SayHi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }
}
```

The question is - How to call method SayHi from another class without pushing `logger`, `env` and `config`?

No I initialize new object with parameters, but I sure that it is wrong:

```
var sendEmaiServiceProvider = new SendEmaiServiceProvider(_config, _env, _logger);
sendEmaiServiceProvider.SayHi();
```

I can create an empty constructor but I will not have `_fromEmailAddress` value.

Comment: .net has been pushing to dependency injection. you should inject your `SendEmaiServiceProvider`

Comment: Is it okay to provide `null` as arguments? What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to add more source code to show the full picture you have.

Comment: Are you looking for a static method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a netcore website. Assuming so, then:

1. Create an `interface` for the dependency.
2. Register the dependency in `Startup.cs`
3. Request the dependency as needed from the netcore DI.

```cs
public interface ISendEmaiServiceProvider
{
  void SayHi()
}

public class SendEmaiServiceProvider : ISendEmaiServiceProvider
{
  public void SayHi() { }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
  services.AddScoped<ISendEmaiServiceProvider, SendEmaiServiceProvider>();
}
```

Then in the Controller (or wherever else DI is used), request it in the `.ctor` and all the dependencies for `SendEmaiServiceProvider` will be filled automatically by DI.

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public readonly ISendEmaiServiceProvider _emailService;

  public HomeController( ISendEmaiServiceProvider emailService )
  {
    _emailService = emailService
  }
}
```

That should get you going.

Comment: Got it. It is clear now. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You should use dependency injection here. Better you create an interface here and resolve your 'SendEmaiServiceProvider' on the startup. And then use the interface instead of creating a new instance for SayHi() method.

```
public interface YourInterface
{
  void SayHi()
}

public class SendEmaiServiceProvider : YourInterface
{
  public void SayHi() 
  { 
    //your code
  }
}
```

On your startup,

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
  services.AddScoped<YourInterface, SendEmaiServiceProvider>();
}
```

On your controller/service,

```
 public class YourController : Controller
    {
      public readonly YourInterface _emailSenderService;
    
      public HomeController( YourInterface emailSenderService )
      {
        _emailSenderService = emailSenderService
      }
    
     
    
    public IActionResult SayHI()    
    {
    _emailSenderService.SayHi()
    }    
   }
```